# Is there a way to make JavaScript mandatory in Struts 2?

Tags: javascript, struts2

What I'm thinking is that I want to use the Struts 2 JSON result type to load all of my data for my pages where ever possible. In theory, this will eliminate or at least greatly reduce the use of JSTL, Struts 2 tags, OGNL, Struts 2 page mappings, Scriptlets, etc. etc. My pages will be nearly, if not completely pure HTML and JavaScript/JQuery.

Consequently, I would like to know if there is a means within Struts 2 or some other means to require that JavaScript be enabled? An Interceptor, perhaps? Anyone know of such a trick?  Perhaps if I use HTML 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't require Javascript to be enabled from with the Struts framework itself. But you can put checks on your pages to warn users that Javascript is required in order to access the application.

Comment: What about using something like: <noscript><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://site.com/pleaseTurnOnJava.jsp"></noscript> ...or perhaps if I put the meta tag in and then used JavaScript to remove it?

Comment: OK, apparently all I need is this on every page:  <noscript>This page requires JavaScript. You must turn it on in order for this page to function.</noscript>  Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_noscript.asp  What it does is replace the entire page with this text.

Comment: Well... if all your content is provided by JSON consuming scripts in your pages your site MUST be used with JS.  What you have said above warns someone to enable JS... but using JSON in general forces the use of JS in the browser. BTW, as someone who has done exactly what you're thinking about I'm not convinced it will greatly reduce the use of tags.  It might depending on how far out you go, but the struts2 url tag is very useful in the JS it self. In this way the application can be deployed anywhere without rewriting urls.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that if you don't actually use the Struts mappings... if you use Struts just for the JSON result types, then you should be able to use static pages with relative references, etc.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with Struts 2 and I haven't launched off into this experiment just yet. The overall idea, of course, is to resurrect the concept of having a UI-only developer. An expert in UI design. We know how customers love well designed UI's.